# Flutter theme not being overridden

Tags: flutter

I've been trying to override my app theme for hours now without success, and I'd be very grateful for any help I can get.

I think I'm doing exactly what [this questioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52345077/cleanly-overriding-parts-of-a-theme-locally-in-flutter) is doing, but for me the theme is not overridden for some reason and I can't understand why. No matter what I do the text 'hey' is not white. Any ideas why? Thank you.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final ThemeData _themeData = Theme.of(context);
  return Theme(
    data: _themeData.copyWith(
      textTheme: _themeData.textTheme.copyWith(
        headline: _themeData.textTheme.headline.copyWith(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        'hey',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized the reason why it didn't work is because the theme needs to be overridden before the build method! Then the context will be of the new theme.

Comment: before the build method we don't have a context unless we explicitly add it as argument to the widget. How would you then use the existing theme?

Answer (score 1):

`Text style` is updated using - `DefaultTextStyle`. `Text` does not use Theme.

Text uses `DefaultTextStyle`, which is edited by MaterialApp (or some other widgets such as AppBar) with values from the Theme.

Working Code:

```
body: Center(
          child: DefaultTextStyle(
            style: TextStyle().copyWith(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            child: Text(
              'hey', // red color
              // style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

**Update:** at `MaterialApp` theme level.

```
class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
            textTheme: TextTheme(headline: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent))),
        home: MyApp());
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData _themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'hey', // red color
            style: _themeData.textTheme.headline,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To update on the fly:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData _themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'hey', //Green color
            style: _themeData.textTheme.headline.apply(color: Colors.green),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Your solution works if the style of the Text is not set cause then the DefaultTextStyle is used, but I want to be able to apply the color white to both textTheme.headline and textTheme.body1 of my main theme, and for that I need to use the style parameter in the text, so the DefaultTextStyle will not be used. That's why I want to do a similar solution as the link I sent. Or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: then you have to define it @ MaterialApp theme level. - updated answer. @Dandido

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. This is more close to what I'm after. I already have a theme at the MaterialApp level. What I am trying to do now in my widget is to copy that theme in but change the headline and body1 text colors to white. I want to do it once and not have to apply it for every headline in my widget. I just want to override my theme locally. If that is possible?

In the end I want to be able to write this and for it to be white
    `Text('hey', style: _themeData.textTheme.headline,),`

Comment: See when you define `style` property of text - `Text('hey', style: _themeData.textTheme.headline,),` it will always pick color that is define at `MaterialApp`. You can only overwrite it with `DefaultTextStyle`. But then you can't use `style` property of text.  Like - `DefaultTextStyle(
            style: _themeData.textTheme.headline.copyWith(color: Colors.green),
            child: Text(
              'hey', // green color
            ),
          ),`

Comment: Reading [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes#themes-for-part-of-an-application) makes me think it should be possible to override a theme locally, do you mean that is incorrect? 

[This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52345077/cleanly-overriding-parts-of-a-theme-locally-in-flutter) also seems to override the font theme, or am I missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126972/flutter-themedata-is-not-working-for-the-text/54127295#54127295

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189128/discussion-between-dandido-and-anmol-majhail).